# Dice sim in python with infinite, customizable dice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working on the classic "build a dice sim in python" school project, and i was trying to make it extremely overcomplicated. basically, what i am attempting is a way to, when you press a button, instead of rolling a dice with n sides x amounts of times, I want to roll x  dice, each with their own amounts of sides. i am extremely unknowledgable with python, so i don't even know if this is possible. from what i do know, it seems like it would take an infinate amount of variables, because there is no real way to "save" the information when you create it. here is my code, which does work:

```
from random import randint

stop="c"
dicenumb=0

print ("Automatic Dice Roller")

while stop !="x":
    if stop == "c":
        print ("Type how many dice you want to roll, then press enter.")
        d=input("")
        print ("Type how many sides you want each dice to have, then press enter.")
        s=input("")
        print("rolling %s dice with %s side(s)!" % (d,s))
    for x in range (0,int(d)):
        dicenumb += 1
        print("Dice # %s is...%s!" % (dicenumb,randint(1,int(s))))
    dicenumb=0
    print("Press enter to roll, c then enter to change the amount of dice and sides, or x then enter to exit!")
    stop=input("")
```

here is the code that I am working on, in order to attempt this:

```
from random import randint

stop="c"
dicenumb=0
dicecust=0
print ("Automatic Dice Roller")

while stop !="x":
    if stop == "c":
        print ("if you want to enter the values of each dice individually, press i, then enter. Otherwise, press enter")
        ind=input("")
        if ind != "i":
            print ("Type how many dice you want to roll, then press enter.")
            d=input("")
            print ("Type how many sides you want each dice to have, then press enter.")
            s=input("")
            print("rolling %s dice with %s side(s)!" % (d,s))
            for x in range (0,int(d)):
                dicenumb += 1
                print("Dice # %s is...%s!" % (dicenumb,randint(1,int(s))))
            dicenumb=0
        else
            for x in range (0,int(d)):
                print ("how many dice would you like to roll? maximum of 10.")
                custnumb=input("")
                dicecust += 1
                print "how many sides would you like dice #%s to have?" % dicecust 
    print("Press enter to roll, c then enter to change the amount of dice and sides, or x then enter to exit!")
    stop=input("")
```

Comment: Have you learned how to use lists yet?  This is an *excellent* use case for lists.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Build a list of all the dice you want to roll, and then iterate through the list:

```
from random import randint

n = int(input("How many dice would you like to roll?\n"))
dice = [
    int(input(f"How many sides would you like die #{i} to have?\n"))
    for i in range(1, n + 1)
]
for i, die in enumerate(dice, 1):
    print(f"Die #{i} is... {randint(1, die)}!")
```

```
How many dice would you like to roll?
6
How many sides would you like die #1 to have?
4
How many sides would you like die #2 to have?
100
How many sides would you like die #3 to have?
6
How many sides would you like die #4 to have?
6
How many sides would you like die #5 to have?
20
How many sides would you like die #6 to have?
100
Die #1 is... 1!
Die #2 is... 51!
Die #3 is... 4!
Die #4 is... 6!
Die #5 is... 9!
Die #6 is... 57!
```